# Getting results from a table with 4 variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image: This table]

This table takes 4 scores (Upper arm, Lower arm, wrist and wrist twist) from a user filling out an assessment form. The scores are then combined to determine a level of severity (1 to 9). So if upper arm scored 6, lower arm scored 2, wrist and wrist twist both scored 1, the level of severity will be 8.

[see what I mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Whgb.jpg)

I want to write a code that will generate the level of severity for the user automatically, so they don't have to use this table.

I'm not sure if there is any equation that was used to plug these four numbers to produce results you see in the table. It's taken from an old thesis paper with no explanation on how the results are calculated.

All I have is this table so I'm not sure how to approach this problem, perhaps something to do with multi dimensional arrays? Sorry I'm new to programming and I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Create a 4-dimensional array, and use all the scores as indexes.

Comment: Model this table in JS and then look up what the associated values are? Or simplify it even further with a single plain object, where key `"1111"` maps to 1, key `"4232"` maps to 5, etc since each value is uniquely located with four single digit numbers. You of course _can_ use equations, but then emphasis on plural. Why try to do with a single equation what can done much easier with several equations that are picked based on what only some of the keys are.